# How do I pass a dictionary to an ansible ad-hoc command?

Tags: ansible

If I have an ansible ad-hoc command that wants a dictionary or list valued argument, like the `queries` argument to `postgresql_query`, how do I invoke that in `ansible` ad-hoc commands?

Do I have to write a one-command playbook? I'm looking for a way to minimise the numbers of layers of confusing quoting (shell, yaml/json, etc) involved.

The ansible docs mention accepting structured forms for variables. So I tried the yaml and json syntax for the arguments:

```
ansible -m postgresql_query -sU postgres -a '{"queries":["SELECT 1", "SELECT 2"]}'
```

... but got `ERROR! this task 'postgresql_query' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: ...`.

the same is true if I `@include` a file with yaml or json contents like

```
cat > 'query.yml' <<'__END__'
queries:
  - "SELECT 1"
  - "SELECT 2"
__END__
ansible -m postgresql_query -sU postgres -a @queries.yml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ansible (2.14.2) it looks like you can specify the JSON directly

Tried this based on the answers given here and it worked.

Here I'm returning facts gathered by [Ansible's setup module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) for host group "psu" filtering output to only see two facts based on a list of filter patterns. The JSON is a dictionary with a single key whose value is a list of filter patterns.

```
ansible psu -m setup -a '{ "filter": ["ansible_distribution_version", "kernel"] }'
```

Output:

```
psu1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution_version": "8.7",
        "ansible_kernel": "5.4.17-2136.318.7.1.el8uek.x86_64"
    },
    "changed": false
}
psu2 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution_version": "8.7",
        "ansible_kernel": "5.4.17-2136.318.7.1.el8uek.x86_64"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can define a dictionary in a JSON variable to pass it as parameter next:

```
ansible -m module_name -e '{"dict": {"key": "value"}}' -a "param={{ dict }}"
```

(parameters positions are arbitrary)

Answer (score 0):

I have most of a solution - a way to express something like a shell script or query payload without extra quoting. But it's *ugly*:

```
ansible hostname -m postgresql_query -sU postgres -a 'query="{{query}}"' -e @/dev/stdin <<'__END__'
query: |
   SELECT 'no special quotes needed' AS "multiline
   identifier works fine" FROM 
   generate_series(1,2)
__END__
```

Not only is that shamefully awful, but it doesn't seem to work for lists (arrays):

```
ansible hostname -m postgresql_query -sU postgres -vvv -a 'query="{{query}}"' -e @/dev/stdin <<'__END__'
queries:
  - |
    SELECT 1
  - |
    SELECT 2
__END__
```

fails with

```
hostname | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "err": "syntax error at or near \"<\"\nLINE 1: <bound method Templar._query_lookup of <ansible.template.Tem...\n        ^\n", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "autocommit": false, 
            "conninfo": "", 
            "queries": null, 
            "query": "<bound method Templar._query_lookup of <ansible.template.Templar object at 0x7f72531c61d0>>"
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Database query failed"
}
```

so it looks like some kind of lazy evaluation is breaking things.